# Refrescar el valor de una lista

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente lista que trae unas Jerarquías, lo que necesito es que cuando el tipo de persona cambie, el tipo de documento borre el valor que tiene guardado, alguien sabe cómo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column" name="form1">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Tipo de persona<span class="has-text-danger">*</span></label>
                <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                    <select id="TipoP" name="TipoP" >
                        <option id="" disabled selected >Seleccione un valor</option>
                        <option id="11925" value="11925" onclick="remove(11925)">Persona Jurídica Extranjera</option>
                        <option id="1223" value="1223" onclick="remove(1223)" >Persona Jurídica Nacional</option>
                        <option id="11924" value="11924" onclick="remove(11924)">Persona Natural Extranjera</option>
                        <option id="1222" value="1222" onclick="remove(1222)">Persona Natural Nacional</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> 

```
    <div class="column">
        <label class="label">Tipo de documento<span class="has-text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="select is-fullwidth">
            <select id="Td" >
                <option id="Sv" disabled selected>Seleccione un valor</option>
                <option style="display: none;" id="1225" value="1225">Cédula de extranjería</option>
                <option style="display: none;" id="1224" value="1224">Cédula de ciudadanía</option>
                <option style="display: none;" id="1921" value="1921">Pasaporte</option>
                <option style="display: none;" id="11943" value="11943">TAX ID</option>                  
                <option style="display: none;" id="1300" value="1300">NIT</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> 

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que compartir tu código para poderte ayudar así como también que has probado hasta el momento.

Comment: Como dice @Ali coloca tu código para poder ayudarte

Comment: @Ali  Listo ya puse las fotos

Comment: Amigo, coloca el código no imágenes

Comment: @JosueVargas Ya

Comment: Verifica la respuesta que te dieron a ver si te sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que tienes varios **select**, puedes usar código `JavaScript` y usar el evento `onChange`, como en el ejemplo:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var person1 = document.getElementById("person");
  var card1 = document.getElementById("card");
  person1.onchange = function() {
    card1.value = "none";
  }
}
```

...

```
<select id="person">
  <option value="unknown">NADIE</option>
  <option value="lady">PRIMERA DAMA</option>
  <option value="granie">ABUELITA</option>
  <option value="chick">SUPERMODELO</option>
</select>
<select id="card">
  <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
  <option value="driver">Licencia de Conducir</option>
  <option value="library">Credencial de Biblioteca</option>
  <option value="passport">Passporte</option>
</select>
```

Si eliges una nueva persona, inmediatamente se reinicia el documento de Identificacion ("card") a Ninguno... `window.onload` es necesario para que ya existan los objetos "person" y "card" del DOM cuando se ejecute el `JavaScript`.